# Liferay autofields - how to pass variables from edit.jsp to view.jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, autofield

I have a problem with Liferay autofields. In my portlet's edit.jsp I'm able to add fields and save it. After getting back in view.jsp fields are no longer available.

I want my list of items to be in both of jsp's, is this possible to achieve?

Here is my code for `edit.jsp`:

```
 <portlet:defineObjects />

 <portlet:renderURL var="editItemURL">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />
 </portlet:renderURL>

 <portlet:renderURL var="viewItemURL">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/view.jsp" />
 </portlet:renderURL>

 <%
 PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();

 List<String> items = Collections.emptyList();

 String itemIndexesParam = renderRequest.getParameter("itemIndexes");

 if (itemIndexesParam != null) {    

 prefs.setValue("itemIndexes", itemIndexesParam);

 prefs.store();
 }

 int[] itemIndexes = null;

 if (Validator.isNotNull(itemIndexesParam)) {
items = new ArrayList<String>();

itemIndexes = StringUtil.split(itemIndexesParam, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
prefs.setValue("items"+i, items.get(i));
itemIndexesParam = String.valueOf(itemIndexes[i]);
    prefs.store();
}
 }
 else {
if (items.isEmpty()) {
    items = new ArrayList<String>();
    itemIndexes = new int[] {0};
}

if (itemIndexes == null) {
    itemIndexes = new int[0];
}
 }

for (int i = 0; i < itemIndexes.length ; i++) {
    items.add(i, (String)prefs.getValue("item"+i, "hello"));
}

%>

<h1>Liferay auto fields example</h1>
<aui:form action="<%= editItemURL%>" method="post" name="LiferayAautoFieldForm"      id="add-menu-item">
<div id="menu-fields">
 <%
     for (int i = 0; i < itemIndexes.length; i++) {
                 int menuIndex = itemIndexes[i];
                 String name = items.get(i);
     %>
    <aui:model-context bean="<%= name %>" model="<%= String.class %>" />

    <div class="lfr-form-row lfr-form-row-inline">
    <div class="row-fields">
        <aui:input label="Content:" fieldParam='<%= "menuItem" + menuIndex %>' name='<%= "item" + menuIndex %>' id='<%= "menuItem" + menuIndex %>' type="textarea" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
<%
   }
%>
<aui:input name="itemIndexes" type="hidden" value="<%= StringUtil.merge(itemIndexes) %>" />
</div>
<aui:layout>
    <aui:column>
        <aui:button type="submit" value="Save Menu Items" name="SaveMenuItems" ></aui:button>
    </aui:column>
</aui:layout>

<aui:script use="liferay-auto-fields">
new Liferay.AutoFields(
   {
       contentBox: '#menu-fields',
       fieldIndexes: '<portlet:namespace />itemIndexes'
   }
).render();
</aui:script>
</aui:form>

items list = <%= items %> <br>
item size = <%= items.size() %> <br>

<a href="<%= viewItemURL %>"><input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Exit edit mode" id="opener"></a>
```

And in `view.jsp` I'm using:

```
<%
PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();

String itemIndexesParam = renderRequest.getParameter("itemIndexes");

List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

int[] itemIndexes = StringUtil.split(itemIndexesParam, 0);

for (int itemIndex : itemIndexes) {
items.add(itemIndex, (String)prefs.getValue("item"+itemIndex, "hello"));
}
%>

<portlet:renderURL var="editNavigationURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

items list = <%= items %> <br>
item size = <%= items.size() %> <br>
```

My code for autofields is (hopefully) working fine, but I'm not able to pass anything back into view.jsp.

What Am I missing?

Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting itemIndexes parameter in edit controller from request , you have to set it back as render parameter in actionResponse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But after adding `actionResponse.setRenderParameter("itemIndexes", itemIndexesParam);` below the render Request I get null pointer exception.

Comment: Where exactly you are getting NPE?

Comment: The exception is thrown directly by the added new line with actionResponse. I'm quite new in Liferay, so it's possible that I've misunderstood your advice. Maybe I should have put it somwhere else?

Comment: OK, the problem is solved - it was right as you said. Thanks for your help!